# external Auth provider exceeding url character limit for azure app service

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an auth server using identity server 4 that allows external auth provider from Microsoft.

When I try to authenticate via my client application the url returned by Microsoft is greater than the 2048 character limit.  my understanding is that this limit cannot be increased when hosting via an app service plan but I could be wrong.

the best solution would be to adjust my auth server to use post to authenticate with Microsoft and not get.  however I am at a loss to how this is achieved.

currently in my startup class the external auth is setup via this code.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
        {
            microsoftOptions.ClientId = "******************";
            microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "************************";
            
        });
```

I can't see a sutable option within the

```
public class MicrosoftAccountOptions : OAuthOptions
```

Class

I would appreciate any input on this or guidance if I am approaching this from the wrong angle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to set is the response_mode property when you do the initial authentication request and set it to form_post, like:

```
response_mode=form_post
```

Typically in a client you use the **AddOpenIdConnect** method to add OpenIDConnect support and then you can set the response mode to return as a post instead like this:

.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
options.ResponseMode = "form_post";
...
}

Hope this helps. I am not sure how you do it using AddMicrosoftAccount.

Comment: Thanks was exactly what I needed